# How to reject a change in onSharedPreferenceChanged() listener

Tags: android, validation, sharedpreferences

The `onSharedPreferenceChanged()` listener does not have a boolean type to return, as the `onPreferenceChanged()` listener has.

So how can one reject a change after validation?

The only way that occurs to me is to keep all shared preferences stored in local variables and if the validation fails, restore the value from the local variable, if it passes update the local variable.

Is this doing double work? Is there a built-in mechanism for reject?

Comment: who changes your `SharedPreference` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this doing double work?

I think so. If one part of the code is going to reject this change, why did another part of the code permit it?

> Is there a built-in mechanism for reject?

The user input should be validated in `onPreferenceChange` before it is committed. It looks like the purpose of `onSharedPreferenceChanged` is not validation but to receive a read-only live update when a change has been committed.

Since other code could receive this callback and act on it, it's too late to validate during this callback.

Reference (the Preference javadoc):

> This class provides the View to be displayed in the activity and associates with a SharedPreferences to store/retrieve the preference data

Comment: Two comments: The "other part of the code" is the user changing a preference, so I need to validate it first and then accept or reject it. Second, `onPreferenceChange()` is for Preferences, not for `SharedPreferences`, which is the case here.

Comment: A Preference is just the UI for a SharedPreference. You should validate in the UI.

Comment: I believe you are not quite right. A `SharedPreference` is the UI for `SharedPreferences`, so says the docs. If you you have some link to new info, I'll be glad to correct my mistake.

Comment: I learned in life that I am almost always wrong, so if you provide me the link to the page where you checked I will go there and learn.

Comment: Last comment, you were right. I set the `onChangePreference()` listener for the specific shared preference I wanted and did the validation there.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you use `setText` to return the value to default if it does not meet your requirements. Then you can show a Toast or whatever to inform the user of the issue.

Here is the solution:

```
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key)
{
    if ("mypref".equals(key)) {
        String value = sharedPreferences.getString(key, "");
        try {
            int v = Integer.parseInt(value);
            // do whatever is needed
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            String deflt = ... # fetch default value 
            EditTextPreference p = (EditTextPreference) findPreference(key);
            p.setText(def);
        }
    }
}
```

Credit: http://androidfromscratch.blogspot.ca/2010/11/validating-edittextpreference.html

Answer (score 0):

You could use the editor: (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#edit()) which allows to make changes atomically and then call commit only if everything is right. I hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately, preferences are mostly for the user to change, and I don't know in advance what is the user going to input instead of the default value.